# How to configure connection Adonis.Js using a cluster MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, adonis.js

I'am setting my connection in **Adonis.js** from **MongoDB.atlas**, but i don't know how complete this configuration.

I have only the connection string currently:

```
mongodb+srv://user:@cluster-6nrle.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

**config/database.js**

```
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Default Connection
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Connection defines the default connection settings to be used while
  | interacting with Mongodb databases.
  |
  */
  connection: Env.get('DB_CONNECTION', 'mongodb'),
  /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

  mongodb: {
    client: 'mongodb',
    connectionString: Env.get('DB_CONNECTION_STRING', 'mongodb+srv://user:<password>@cluster-6nrle.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'),
    connection: {
      host: Env.get('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
      port: Env.get('DB_PORT', 27017),
      username: Env.get('DB_USER', 'admin'),
      password: Env.get('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
      database: Env.get('DB_DATABASE', 'adonis'),
      options: {
        // replicaSet: Env.get('DB_REPLICA_SET', '')
        // ssl: Env.get('DB_SSL, '')
        // connectTimeoutMS: Env.get('DB_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS', 15000),
        // socketTimeoutMS: Env.get('DB_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS', 180000),
        // w: Env.get('DB_W, 0),
        // readPreference: Env.get('DB_READ_PREFERENCE', 'secondary'),
        // authSource: Env.get('DB_AUTH_SOURCE', ''),
        // authMechanism: Env.get('DB_AUTH_MECHANISM', ''),
        // other options
      }
    }
  },
```

I would like to know how I can complete the configuration or something alternative, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

mongodb connection format like this 

`mongodb+srv://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[database][?options]]`

in .env file in put

```
DB_USER=user 
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_HOST=cluster-6nrle.mongodb.net
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE =test
```

change database config file

```
mongodb: {
client: 'mongodb',
connection: {
  host: Env.get('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
  port: Env.get('DB_PORT', 27017),
  username: Env.get('DB_USER', 'admin'),
  password: Env.get('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
  database: Env.get('DB_DATABASE', 'adonis'),
  options: {
  }
```

maybe it's work

Comment: i came across the same issue, here is a solution

https://github.com/duyluonglc/lucid-mongo

Answer (score 0):

i came across the same issue, here is a solution

https://github.com/duyluonglc/lucid-mongo

```js
module.exports = {

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Default Connection
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Connection defines the default connection settings to be used while
  | interacting with Mongodb databases.
  |
  */
  connection: Env.get('DB_CONNECTION', 'mongodb'),
  /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

  mongodb: {
    client: 'mongodb',
    connectionString: Env.get('DB_CONNECTION_STRING', ''),
    connection: {
      host: Env.get('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
      port: Env.get('DB_PORT', 27017),
      username: Env.get('DB_USER', 'admin'),
      password: Env.get('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
      database: Env.get('DB_DATABASE', 'adonis'),
      options: {
        // replicaSet: Env.get('DB_REPLICA_SET', '')
        // ssl: Env.get('DB_SSL, '')
        // connectTimeoutMS: Env.get('DB_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS', 15000),
        // socketTimeoutMS: Env.get('DB_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS', 180000),
        // w: Env.get('DB_W, 0),
        // readPreference: Env.get('DB_READ_PREFERENCE', 'secondary'),
        // authSource: Env.get('DB_AUTH_SOURCE', ''),
        // authMechanism: Env.get('DB_AUTH_MECHANISM', ''),
        // other options
      }
    }
  }
}
```